# A question approximation with compact support function in $H^s$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Give a function $u(x) \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $s \in \mathbb{R},$ which the norm is
$$
\|u \|_{H^s}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^{s} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2d\xi,
$$
here $\hat{u}$ is the Fourier transform of $u.$ I would like to prove that $u$ can be approximated by compact support function in $H^s.$

My attempt is to choose a sequence of appropriate cut-off function $f_\epsilon(x) \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and I hope that $f_\epsilon(x)u(x)$ tend to $u(x)$ in $H^s$ when $\epsilon$ tends to 0.

By definition, and note that $\widehat{f_\epsilon u}=\hat{f}_\epsilon*\hat{u},$ thus we have
\begin{align}  
\| f_\epsilon u(x)-u\|_{H^s}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^s |\hat{f_\epsilon}*\hat{u}-\hat{u}|^2 d\xi.
\end{align}
So I would like to choose $f_\epsilon$ so that $\hat{f_\epsilon}$ is the standard mollifier $\epsilon^{-n}\rho(\frac{\xi}{\epsilon}).$ Here $\rho(\xi)$ is a $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ non-negative function with support in $\{|\xi|\leq 1\}$ and $\int \rho =1.$

However, by Amrein-Berthier theorem in harmonic analysis, a non-zero function and its Fourier transformation cannot be supported on finite measure set simultaneously. Hence the function $f$ doesn't have compact support.

What should I do? Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I don't understand. Could you elucidate your question?

Comment: So you mean that I should find a Schwartz function $\rho$ so that the inverse transform of $\rho$ is compactly supported? But what is this function?

Comment: I still confused. Since $\epsilon^{-n}\rho(\xi/\epsilon)$ is compactly supported, its inverse Fourier transform is not compactly supported by Amrein-Berthier theorem.  Then it does not satisfy my requirement.

Comment: ? no, start from $f$ being compactly supported. You can choose the formula $\hat f = \epsilon^{-n} \rho(\xi/\epsilon)$ without asking for $\rho$ to be compactly supported. This is good enough

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry. I think if $\rho$ is not compactly support, then $\epsilon^{-n}\rho(\dot/\epsilon) * \hat{u}$ doesn't necessarily tends to $\hat{u}$ when $\epsilon$ tends to $0.$

Comment: It does, you just need $\int \rho = 1$. Note if $f_\epsilon(x) = f(\epsilon x)$ then $\widehat{f_\epsilon}(\xi) = \epsilon^{-n} \hat f(x /\epsilon)$ so $\rho= \hat f$ and $\int\rho=1$ means precisely that $f(0)=1$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this proof idea works, but I haven't worked the details out. There is a different proof in chapter 1 of Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin Nonlinear PDEs book

Comment: I have read the proof in B-C-D's book. It is very fascinating. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CalvinKhor The $\rho_\epsilon$ are "good kernels" (see Stein Real Analysis Theorem 2.1), hence the convergence indeed holds.

Comment: Oh, and dominated convergence, I guess? I knew the convergence a.e. but somehow forgot